# jQuery + stopPropagation: Exclude child element from parent selector

Tags: jquery, click, parent-child

***Final working code based on accepted answer***

```
        $('#photo-upload, #photo-upload .close').click(function(){
            $('#photo-upload').removeClass('show');
        });

        $('#upload-button').click(function(){
            $('#photo-upload').addClass('show');
        });

        $('#form-window').click(function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

***original question***

I have a modal window with a close button. The window is triggered by a link `a#upload-button`. `#photo-upload` is a 100% height + width fixed div. `#form-window` is a 200px by 200px box that is centered horizontally and vertically inside of `#photo-upload`

```
<div id="photo-upload">
    <div id="form-window">
        <!-- Content -->
        <a class="close"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The close button is absolutely positioned a little bit beyond the upper right corner. I want to set a click function so that clicking outside the modal window closes the window, and also so that clicking on the close button closes the window. But so that clicking on the window itself does not close the window.

My current code is:

```
$('#photo-upload').click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('#form-window')){
      return false;
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('show');
    }
});

$('#form-window').live("click",function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('a.close')){
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
});


$('#upload-button').live("click", function(){
    $('#photo-upload').addClass('show');
});

$('#photo-upload .close').live("click", function(){
    $('#photo-upload').removeClass('show');
});
```

With the above code, *nothing* happens when I click any of those elements, and can't close the div. What am I doing wrong?

How do I use stopPropagation() on a parent but exclude a child element (in my case, `a.close`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an additional handler to the close button which also closes the window.

```
$(".close").live('click',function(){
            $('#form-window').removeClass('show');
        });
```

Ideally you probably want to actually add the `.close` selector in addition to `document` and only have the function once to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the `target` is not the close link inside the `form-window` `click` handler. It not stop the `event` `propagation` else let the document `click` handler take care of rest. Try this

```
    $(document).live('click',function(){
        $('#form-window').removeClass('show');
    });

    $('#form-window').live("click",function(e){
        if(!$(e.target).is('a.close')){
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `$("a.close").has(e.target).length` will check for children